# Reorder DataFrame rows inplace

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, in-place

Is it possible to reorder `pandas.DataFrame` rows (based on an index) inplace?
I am looking for something like this:

```
df.reorder(idx, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Where `idx` is not equal to but is the same type of `df.index`, it contains the same elements, but in another order. The output is `df` reordered before new `idx`.

I have not found anything in documentation and I fail to use `reindex_axis`. Which made me hoping it was possible because:

> A new object is produced unless the new index is equivalent to the
>   current one and copy=False

I might have misunderstood what equivalent index means in this context.

Comment: Have you tried with `df.reindex` ? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html

Comment: @AdrienMatissart, but it lacks inplace switch.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) function (note that this is not inplace):

```
>>import pandas as pd

>>df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3],'col2':['test','hi','hello']})
>>df 
    col1    col2
0   1   test
1   2   hi
2   3   hello


>>df = df.reindex([2,0,1])
>>df
    col1    col2
2   3   hello
0   1   test
1   2   hi
```

Comment: I am aware of this, but I am looking for inplace reindex

Comment: Ok - sorry I am not aware of such a method.